# Django. Media url not found

Tags: python, django

I have a django project based on django 1.11.
I uploaded media files and try to get them but instead I get nothong.
I read documentation and did exactly as it said.
Also I checked 'media' foleder permissions.

**settings.py:**

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Did you get 404 error?

Comment: No, If I try to open an image by a direct link 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/unsplash.jpg' I get the 'index' page.

Comment: But actually I think it's 404. Because if I add "$" to url in my app then I get 404

Comment: Did you use nginx in server?

Comment: I found my image in '127.0.0.1:8000/media/media/unsplash.jpg'
I have no idea why ...media/media..

Comment: but it works... hm...

Comment: Try to change media_url to `media/`

Comment: nothing change...
I don't know why but now it works!
With the same code. Maybe it was because I have 'media' folder in 'myproject' folder. I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `MEDIA_ROOT` to `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')` in `settings.py` and make sure your media file in project root directory.